# git init --bare on git 1.5.4.3

Tags: git, init, git-bare

We have got git 1.5.4.3 (Version from Feb'08) on our server. As it seems, there was no option `--bare` back then.

How can I create a bare repository then?

Creating it locally and scp'ing it to the server would be an option, but way too much effort.
Or is it possible with a **local** git command to **create a new *remote* repository**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With such an early version of git, you can still create a bare repository with:

```
git --bare init
```

... rather than the more usual `git init --bare`.

---

Out of interest, I found this out from the message for the commit that introduced the `--bare` option to `git init`:

- https://github.com/git/git/commit/74d3b23fe3771c769ccd5c97f6a46682b4061577

That commit is contained in git version v1.5.6 and later.

Comment: +1 from me, other than the fact that IMHO `git --bare init` is much more usual for precisely the reason that it has been around for a lot longer.